# How to sort a Alphanumeric string with special characters in C# using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, special-characters

How to sort a Alphanumeric string with special characters in C# using Linq?
Order should be first special characters, then numbers and then alphabets.

Example :

Input - { Hello, #Test, @Red, &While, 123@Test, @123Test, %54Sun, Dom, Left }

Expected - { @123Test, %54Sun, @Red, #Test, &While, 123@Test, Dom, Hello, Left }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY8kU.png)

Comment: Sort method returns the desired result... not the _Expected_ one that seems to be wrong; could you please add real code, or at least real data?

Comment: Any specific requirements on how to order within the special characters? The standard order function gives: "@123Test", "@Red", "&While", "#Test", "%54Sun", "123@Test", "Dom", "Hello", "Left".

Comment: @KlausGütter No specific requirement within special characters. the order should be first special characters, then numbers and then alphabets. Thanks.

Comment: Then `input.OrderBy(x => x)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @KlausGütter I tried input.OrderBy(x => x) the result I have attached above when I click on column for sort in descending

Comment: Better add this as text, not as image. Your result seems to use different input that the example in your question, right?

Comment: Yes its different example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use custom implementation of [IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?view=net-7.0), then pass it to `OrderBy` call. E.g.:

```
public class SpecialCharactersNumbersLettersComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly IComparer<string> defaultComparer = StringComparer.InvariantCulture;
    
    private static int OrderOfChar(char ch)
    {
        if(Char.IsLetter(ch))
            return 2;
        if(Char.IsDigit(ch))
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    
    public int Compare(string left, string right)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(left)
          || string.IsNullOrEmpty(right)) {
            return defaultComparer.Compare(left, right);
        }
        
        var leftChar = left[0];
        var rightChar = right[0];
        var leftOrder = OrderOfChar(leftChar);
        var rightOrder = OrderOfChar(rightChar);
        
        if(leftOrder == rightOrder)
            return defaultComparer.Compare(left, right);
        
        if(leftOrder > rightOrder)
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}

public static List<string> SortSpecialCharactersNumbersAlphabet(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    return input.OrderBy(_ => _, new SpecialCharactersNumbersLettersComparer())
        .ToList();
}
```

Used as:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
    SortSpecialCharactersNumbersAlphabet(new [] {
    "Hello", "#Test", "@Red", "&While", "123@Test", "@123Test", "%54Sun", "Dom", "Left"})));
```

produces output:

```
@123Test, @Red, &While, #Test, %54Sun, 123@Test, Dom, Hello, Left
```

Answer (score 1):

As the standard string comparison does exactly that, you can just use `OrderBy`:

```
var input = new[] { "Hello", "#Test", "@Red", "&While", "123@Test", "@123Test", "%54Sun", "Dom", "Left" };
foreach (var s in input.OrderBy(x => x)) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Gives:

```
@123Test
@Red
&While
#Test
%54Sun
123@Test
Dom
Hello
Left
```

Since the string comparison is culture-dependent, this might be different depending on your current culture. If you want it culture-independent, use e.g. `OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: This is not working when I want to sort the column manually. It working only for once while loading the UI

Comment: You mean in a DataGridView or similar? What exactly are you doing to sort it and what is the result?

Comment: Yes it is a DataGridView and I am trying to sort by clicking on column

Comment: But this is really something different now. Mabe ask a new question for this.